# Firebase + Angularjs + Python

Tags: javascript, python, model-view-controller, angularjs, firebase

Ok, I'm using the angularFire-seed repo to test out how I would connect angularjs+firebase+python-firebase library.

My goal is to add stuff to firebase from python scripts and have it show on a webpage.

this is a controller:

```
    ......
    angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
       .controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'FBURL', 'angularFire', function($scope,
       FBURL, angularFire) {
       angularFire(FBURL+'/syncedValue', $scope, 'syncedValue', '');
       }])
    ......
```

this is the view:

```
    ......
    <h4>{{syncedValue}}</h4>
    <input ng-model="syncedValue" type="text" />
    ......
```

Everything works fine:

[image]

---

[image: firebase debugger]

It Works! When I input stuff on the webpage, it shows in the firebase debugger.

Now I'm doing this in python:

```
   from firebase import Firebase
   f = Firebase("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/syncedValue")
   r = f.update({"syncedValue": "3433"})
```

That makes a child to syncedValue:

[image: firebase debugger]

```
   r = f.push({"syncedValue": "3433"})
```

That makes a child with a uid:

[image]

But I want to simply just update the syncedValue key's value without adding any child, like this...

[image]

Prollie something in angularjs i'm not understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it!

```
   from firebase import Firebase
   f = Firebase("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/syncedValue")
   r = f.update({"syncedValue": "3433"})**strong text**
```

that code updates a child of syncedValue
so....

I just simply made a child in the controller:

```
  ......
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
   .controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'FBURL', 'angularFire', function($scope,
   FBURL, angularFire) {
   angularFire(FBURL+'/syncedValue/1', $scope, 'syncedValue', '');
   }])
......
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a really simple library available in Python for working with Firebase with less confusing syntax. You should check it out  https://github.com/andela-cnnadi/pyfirebase.

For this case you might want to do something like this

```
from pyfirebase import Firebase
f = Firebase('https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/')
ref = firebase.ref('syncedValue')
ref.set(3433)
```

You can then proceed to update this ref whenever you want using the same syntax:

```
 ref.set("newValue")
```